# Absdiff in openCV can compile but show black image

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I have been trying to use `absdiff` to find the motion in an image,but unfortunately it fail,i am new to OpenCV. The coding supposed to use `absdiff` to determine whether any motion is happening around or not, but the output is a pitch black for `diff1`,`diff2` and `motion`. Meanwhile,`next_mframe`,`current_mframe`, `prev_mframe` shows grayscale images. While, `result` shows a clear and normal image. I use this as my reference http://manmade2.com/simple-home-surveillance-with-opencv-c-and-raspberry-pi/. I think the all the image memory is loaded with the same frame and compare, that explain why its a pitch black. Is there any others method i miss there? I am using RTSP to pass camera **RAW** image to **ROS**.

```
    void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&msg_ptr){

    CvPoint center;
    int radius, posX, posY;

    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_image;     //To parse image_raw from rstp
    try
    {
        cv_image = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg_ptr, enc::BGR8);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
      return;
    }

    frame = new IplImage(cv_image->image);    //frame now holding raw_image
    frame1 = new IplImage(cv_image->image); 
    frame2 = new IplImage(cv_image->image); 
    frame3 = new IplImage(cv_image->image); 

     matriximage = cvarrToMat(frame);
     cvtColor(matriximage,matriximage,CV_RGB2GRAY);  //grayscale

     prev_mframe = cvarrToMat(frame1);
     cvtColor(prev_mframe,prev_mframe,CV_RGB2GRAY);  //grayscale
     current_mframe = cvarrToMat(frame2);
     cvtColor(current_mframe,current_mframe,CV_RGB2GRAY);  //grayscale
     next_mframe = cvarrToMat(frame3);
     cvtColor(next_mframe,next_mframe,CV_RGB2GRAY);  //grayscale

     // Maximum deviation of the image, the higher the value, the more motion is allowed
    int max_deviation = 20;

    result=matriximage;

    //rellocate image in right order
    prev_mframe = current_mframe;
    current_mframe = next_mframe;
    next_mframe = matriximage;
    //motion=difflmg(prev_mframe,current_mframe,next_mframe);

    absdiff(prev_mframe,next_mframe,diff1); //Here should show black and white image
    absdiff(next_mframe,current_mframe,diff2);
    bitwise_and(diff1,diff2,motion);
    threshold(motion,motion,35,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    erode(motion,motion,kernel_ero);


    imshow("Motion Detection",result);
    imshow("diff1",diff1);  //I tried to output the image but its all black
    imshow("diff2",diff2);  //same here, I tried to output the image but its all black
    imshow("diff1",motion);
    imshow("nextframe",next_mframe);
    imshow("motion",motion);

    char c =cvWaitKey(3);  }
```

Comment: 1. don't use the IplImage api, it's outdated. Use cv::Mat instead! 2. I guess that your `frame3 = new IplImage(cv_image->image);` doesn't copy the data but uses the same memory. You'll need deep-copy methods instead. This would explain why your adsDiff is 0 everywhere, if you just subtract the identical image from itself.

Comment: Thank you, does that mean if i use deep copy method which is CopyTo() and Clone() functions can help in solving this problem? I am using ROS to subsribe raw image using the function cv_bridge, does cv::Mat support for Raw Image too? Or a conversion from IplImage to Mat is needed?

Comment: try to clone or copyTo instead of assignment, in all the cvArrToMat lines and in the whole "//rellocate image in right order" part, too. However, in your sample code, frame, frame1, frame2 and frame3 will hold identical image information, anyways? Try to load/use different images! It looks like you are only trying to run the initialization code and there might be missing a loop where you load new images and update prev/current/next frame iteratively??

Comment: I think i figure out the problems, i cannot use cv_bridge to save the image, i need to use VideoCap functions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the cv_bridge method to VideoCap, its seem to functions well, cv_bridge just cannot save the image even through i change the IplImage to Mat format. Maybe there is other ways, but as for now, i will go with this method fist.

```
VideoCapture cap(0); 
Tracker(void)
{
    //check if camera worked
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"cannot open the Video cam"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"camera is opening"<<endl;

    cap>>prev_mframe;
    cvtColor(prev_mframe,prev_mframe,CV_RGB2GRAY);  // capture 3 frame and convert to grayscale
    cap>>current_mframe;
    cvtColor(current_mframe,current_mframe,CV_RGB2GRAY);  
    cap>>next_mframe;
    cvtColor(next_mframe,next_mframe,CV_RGB2GRAY); 

    //rellocate image in right order
    current_mframe.copyTo(prev_mframe);
    next_mframe.copyTo(current_mframe);
    matriximage.copyTo(next_mframe);

    motion = diffImg(prev_mframe, current_mframe, next_mframe);
}
```